# Как использовать разные view при одинаковой структуре url в Django

Tags: python, django

Есть 2 разных модели. Например, категории и товары. Как сделать, чтобы можно было их запускать с одного уровня вложенности урла?

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<category_slug>/', CategoryListView.as_view(), name='category_view'),
    path('<product_slug>/', ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='product_view'),
]
```

Вот в этом примере я  хочу запускать либо CategoryListView либо ProductDetailView в зависимости от того какой слаг попадает в урл - категории или продукта. Но Джанго обрабатывает только первую ссылку, т.к. она подходит под условие и считает, что запрашивают отсутствующую категорию. Как с этим быть?

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужна вьюха-"посредник", которая будет направлять на одну из указанных.

views.py:

```
def middleware_view(request, slug):
    try: # пробуем достать категорию
        Category.objects.get(slug_field=slug) # если тут выпадет с ошибкой - return не сработает
        return CategoryListView.as_view()(request, slug) # если не выпала ошибка - вернем вьюху
    except Category.DoesNotExist: # выпала ошибка - пробуем дальше
        try:
            Product.objects.get(slug_field=slug)
            return ProductDetailView.as_view()(request, slug)
        except Product.DoesNotExist: # выпала ошибка и тут?
            raise Http404 # вернем 404 ошибку
```

urls.py:

```
path('<slug>/', views.middleware_view, name='middleware')
```